# Usage of "due to" and "because" - are they interchangeble?

Tags: conjunctions

Are both the following sentences correct?

> He is not coming to school due to he fell sick last night.
>   He is not coming to school because he fell sick last night.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are not interchangeable. "Due to" has to be followed by a noun phrase and "because" - by a clause (which means there will be a verb after it). So in your examples, the second sentence is correct. A correct example with "due to" will be: "*His company's success was mostly due to the excellent performance of the manager.*"

Comment: Yes. You might add that in the most exacting registers *due to* is deployed (as you have done) as head of an adjectival clause rather than of an adverbial clause: *N (is) due to N* rather than *S due to N*. *His absence from school today is due to illness last night*.

Comment: @StoneyB, I don't understand the point you make. Could you give an example using an adverbial clause, please?

Comment: @Nico Apologies for the shorthand. *N* stands for noun or nominal, S for sentence. Very formal writing deprecates using a *due to N* phrase as a sentence modifier, as in *He is absent due to sickness*. Instead you should say *His absence is due to sickness* or *He is absent because he is sick.*