# Can "due to" mean "resulted from"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Consider:

> To enhance insight on the ionic liquid structure, RDFs **due to** correlations between atomic sites on each ion were calculated.

I guess "due to" means "resulted from" here. Does it have such a meaning? Here, we have one clause. Should we expect a second clause whenever a "due to" is used?

This is another [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30004/object-complement-after-due-to) with similar title but the contents of the question and answer don't deal with "due to" as expected here.

Comment: "due to" means "according to" or "because of". Your sentence sounds off to me.

Comment: Well, maybe it's not so bad. I probably got lost in all that scientific talk of yours.

Comment: Your sentence is fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [object complement after "due to"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30004/object-complement-after-due-to)

Comment: insight **into**...

Comment: **resulting from** would be better here than **due to**.

Comment: The answer to other question covers other things and I don't think they are the same.

Comment: You shouldn't use abbreviations in examples where the grammar is in question, especially when they are not generally known. If the full form is not available or not generally known, you should substitute another term that will hold the same meaning.

Answer (score 3):

**"due to"** has many meaning one of which is **"ascribable to"**. The following sentence reads as follows:

- To enhance insight on the ionic liquid structure, radial distribution functions (RDFs) *ascribable to* correlations between atomic sites on each ion were calculated.

For those who can't see the meaning:

- [Ascribe/Ascribable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ascribable) - *to regard as arising from a specified cause or source; capable of being assigned or credited to*

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound quite right ... but the truth is if I read it in a scientific journal I would accept it as a new kind of jargon.  It feels like shorthand for "that occur as a result of ..." or something similar.  I'm not quite sure how the RDFs get produced so I don't know the exact verb to use.

Anyway, if you read this in a journal follow the basic rule: Imitate others.